# Need an example using std::vector in Qt

Tags: qt, opengl, stdvector

I have a UI (used Qt creator) that I am working on that creates opengl models at runtime, such that when I click a button it draws a cube or any other model.
Can anyone please show me an example of how the c++ container class std::vector can be used for this in Qt ?

Comment: Your question is missing vital information. For example, you say that you have "opengl models". Well... what object are you currently using to store those models? Is it copyable? Are you trying to put that object in a `vector`, or are you doing something else? And how does Qt have *anything* to do with this? Qt is just for your GUI setup and management; how you render is between you and OpenGL.

Comment: I actually meant I have opengl models..sorry for the mistake. I want to put those models (triangles, cubes etc..) in the vector, and use Qpushbutton to call them

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to use std::vector in Qt. Are they pure C++ objects. Look into QList, QVector and variants (they also offer STL like iterators).

I can think of no reason why you cannot use std::vector in a Qt project.

Comment: They are opengl models which I want to put in a stack, so they can be called with a pushbutton

Comment: In your QPushButton signal handler you can just iterate your std::vector (assuming that the object containing the vector - if not the same object - is known).